# Is it faster to copy reference to object from dictionary or access it directly from dictionary?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

Question is simple

is this code

```
public Dictionary<string, SomeObject> values = new Dictionary<string, SomeObject>();

void Function()
{
    values["foo"].a = "bar a";
    values["foo"].b = "bar b";
    values["foo"].c = "bar c";
    values["foo"].d = "bar d";
}
```

same fast as this code

```
public Dictionary<string, SomeObject> values = new Dictionary<string, SomeObject>();

void Function()
{
    var someObject = values["foo"];
    someObject.a = "bar a";
    someObject.b = "bar b";
    someObject.c = "bar c";
    someObject.d = "bar d";
}
```

common sense tell me that it should be faster to look up the reference in dictionary once and store it somewhere so that it doesn't need to be looked up multiple times, but I don't really know how dictionary works.

So is it faster or not? And why?

Comment: Have *you* actually tried testing whether there is a speed difference?

Comment: why don't you run a benchmark test and see

Comment: No I haven't, I have no idea how to benchmark code

Comment: @Petr Saying you have no idea how to do something in programming is like Neo in the matrix saying he doesn't know `Kung Fu`. Just do a 30 second google search and voila.

Comment: well, first you write something like `DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now`.  and then you write the code you want to benchmark, and then you write `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Frames - startTime.Frames`

Comment: Speed is hardly relevant in a case like this, but I would think you're right, the last one is fastest, though it might depend on how many properties (or fields) you need to assign to. Is it really four? I think you should choose which-ever you like best. Speed is not important here.

Comment: @SamIam It would be better to use the `Stopwatch` class than to rely on `DateTime.Now`. Also, in .NET the `DateTime` struct has no `Frames` property. You can directly subtract two `DateTime` values (the result being a `TimeSpan` value).

Comment: Is it a certainty that these two approaches even generate different IL code?

Comment: @SamIam I am a newbie to benchmarking, but I know that there are several optimizations behind the code execution, and the results are not always clear. For example in this very case the compiler could just change the code to what I have in second block, to make it faster, but it complex case it would left it as it is (so in one case I would see no difference in speed and in some other case there could be some). That's why I am asking here, people who really know the answer, rather than trying to calculate it myself

Comment: @SamIam I think you want `Ticks`, not `Frames`, right? And I agree with @JeppeStigNielsen - the `Stopwatch` was designed for that, so I'd go with it.

Comment: No, the compiler is not allowed to "optimize" the first code into the equivalent of the second code, because `values` is a `public` field, and the compiler cannot know if some other thread will be running which changes the entry for `"foo"`, so it has to lookup every time if you demand that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, you are correct. Your first approach does the dictionary lookup 4 times, while the second does it once. The second is definitely better.

However, in real life, a dictionary lookup is ridiculously fast, so unless you've got a massive dictionary the difference won't be noticeable, maybe not even measurable.

Comment: Note the size of the dictionary is not relevant here, as lookups are O(1).  All that matters is how many lookups you do, so if this code is in a loop that runs a large number of times (even if the dictionary being looked up is not large), then it might matter.

Comment: Noticeable, probably not. Measurable, certainly. The code has to compute the hash value and do a lookup. Also, the size of the dictionary is irrelevant. Looking something up in a dictionary of 1,000,000 items will take no longer than in a dictionary of only 1,000 items. Unless the dictionary is full (high load factor). Then it acts more like a sequential search.

Comment: For fun, I created dictionaries of 1,000 and 1,000,000 items many times, then did 5,000,000 lookups on them (Guid key). It took about 2.5 seconds to do the lookups against 1,000 items, and 3.5 seconds to do them against 1,000,000 items. Very consistent results. So I'd say that the size of the dictionary does matter, although not dramatically.

Comment: @JimMischel You're right, it has to be measurable in some manner. But possibly not measurable in milliseconds, even for lots of real-life lookups, which is what I had in mind. But it's so easy to optimize this, that I wouldn't skip it just because it probably won't be a factor.

Comment: @JoeEnos In your performance test, did you lookup the same item, or was it random items?

Comment: @niry That was three and a half years ago, I don't think I still have that code...But it should be pretty easy to recreate if you want to try it.

Answer (score 6):

Joe's absolutely right, but as if it wasn't enough I've done a simple obvious test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();
    var number = 10000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        dict[i.ToString()] = new Foo();
    }

    var watch = new Stopwatch();

    watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        var key = i.ToString();
        dict[key].A = "a";
        dict[key].B = "b";
        dict[key].C = "c";
        dict[key].D = "d";
    }

    watch.Stop();
    Console.Out.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    watch.Reset();

    watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        var key = i.ToString();
        var foo = dict[key];

        foo.A = "a";
        foo.B = "b";
        foo.C = "c";
        foo.D = "d";
    }

    watch.Stop();
    Console.Out.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}   

class Foo
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

On my machine this outputs to:

```
3423
2113
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Having only 1 lookup definitely reduces the total time for big numbers.

Comment: So about 1.3 seconds' difference over 10 million iterations? That's pretty much the definition of "down in the noise," as far as program optimization is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious. The following unit test, (possibly) shows that the second method is about 25% faster. (121 ms vs 91 ms). Going from 6 fields to 2 narrowed the gap, 40 ms vs 33 ms. I say possibly since I wrote this fairly quickly and I'm not convinced it's immune to measuring some side effect, but it shows the expected behavior, so why question it. (hah).

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestProject1
{

public class DataObject
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
    public string F { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    public static Dictionary<string, DataObject> dict = new Dictionary<string, DataObject>();
    static string lookie;

    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext) {

        Random rand = new Random(123545);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            string key = rand.NextDouble().ToString();
            DataObject dob = new DataObject();
            dict.Add(key, dob);
            if (i == 4567)
                lookie = key;
        }

    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
        {
            dict[lookie].A = "val" + j;
            dict[lookie].B = "val" + j;
            dict[lookie].C = "val" + j;
            dict[lookie].D = "val" + j;
            dict[lookie].E = "val" + j;
            dict[lookie].F = "val" + j;
        }
        sw.Stop();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
        {
            DataObject dob = dict[lookie];
            dob.A = "val" + j;
            dob.B = "val" + j;
            dob.C = "val" + j;
            dob.D = "val" + j;
            dob.E = "val" +j;
            dob.F = "val" +j;
        }
        sw.Stop();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you do the timings on a release build with no debugger attached? 25% seems ... excessive.